# Differencing causes negative predictions

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a non - stationary time series sequence which is based on counts. To convert the sequence into stationary I applied differencing, which converted the sequence into stationary but the sequence now has negative values.

```
ts_seq_shifted = ts_seq - ts_seq.shift(1)
```

Now when I use the AR model to predict, I get negative predictions. Ideally my predictions are count which logically cannot be negative.

```
mod = AR(df["ts_seq_shifted"])
res = mod.fit(maxlag= 15, ic= 'bic')
pred = res.predict(start="2001-01-01", end="2001-01-02")
```

op:

```
The predictions for the next 2 days are: 
2001-01-01   -3.958415
2001-01-02   -0.391196
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

In my understanding I did not do over differencing and since I have 0 in the sequence I cannot apply log transformations hence I chose differencing.

Any suggestions to tackle this problem could be really helpful?

Comment: For count time series you need to use a different approach, have a look at `tscount` package.

Comment: And don't forget Tucker's advice : make a graph.

Comment: @AlainD What's Tucker's advice?

Comment: Ledyard Tucker was claiming every one and again : "Make a graph!"